# MySQL - how to optimize large set of conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My head is already spinning from this and I need your help.

**MY DATABASE**

- imported CSV file: 22 columns and **11k rows**
- **2 tables** with the same data (both created from the CSV)
- Added **ID** as *PRIMARY KEY* to both
- All **VARCHAR(60)** Some columns are **empty strings '  '**

DB:

```
PID  | CODE 1 | CODE 2 | CODE 3 | CODE 4 | CODE 5 | CODE X (up to 9) | ID 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1  |   a    |    b   |   c    |        |        |                  |  1
  2  |   a    |        |   b    |    d   |        |                  |  2
  3  |   x    |        |        |        |        |        y         |  3
```

- DB has 22 columns but I'm only including *CODE* columns (up to **9**)
  in which I might be interested in terms of SQL statement.
- It'll be only **read table** - MyISAM engine then?

**WHAT I'D LIKE TO DO**

```
select PID = 1 from first table
and retrieve all PIDs from second table
IF
  selected PID's column CODE 1 
  or 
  selected PID's column CODE 2 (which is b) etc (up to 9). 
  = any PID's CODE X
```

So I should get only PID 2.

**edit:** PID is not a ID, it's just an example code, it could be string: '002451' and I'm looking for other PIDs with the same CODES (e.g `PID1` has `code = a` so it should find `PID2` becasue one of its `CODE` columns contains `a`)

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
SELECT a.* FROM `TABLE1` a WHERE
(
  SELECT * FROM `TABLE2` b WHERE b.`PID` = 1
  AND
    (
    ( b.`CODE 1` NOT IN ('') AND IN (a.`CODE 1`,a.`CODE 2`, A.`CODE 3`...) ) OR
    ( b.`CODE 2` NOT IN ('') AND (a.`CODE 1`,a.`CODE 2`, A.`CODE 3`...) ) OR...
```

I'd end up with large query - over **81 conditions**. In terms of performance... well, it doesn't work.

I intuitively know that **I should**:

- use INDEXES (on CODE 1 / CODE 2 / CODE 3 etc.?)
- use JOIN ON (but I'm too stupid) - that's why I created 2 tables (let's assume I don't want TEMP. TABLES)

How to write the SQL / design the DB efficently?

Comment: Fix your database to have one row per `pid` and `code`.  Have multiple columns with the same data is almost never the right solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? One row per pid and one row per code? Or to reduce these 22 columns to only needed ones.

Answer (score 1):

The correct data structure is one row per `pid` and `code`. The simplest way is:

```
create table PCodes (
    pid int not null,
    code varchar(255),
    constraint fk_PCodes_pid references p(pid)
);
```

Then you have the values in a single column and it is much simpler to check for matching codes.

In practice, you should have three tables:

```
create table Codes (
    CodeId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    Code varchar(255)
);

create table PCodes (
    pid int not null,
    codeid int not null, 
    constraint fk_PCodes_pid references p(pid),
    constraint fk_PCodes_codeid references codes(codeid);
);
```

If the ordering of the codes is important for each "p", then include a `priority` or `ordering` column in the `PCodes` table.

Comment: Oh ok - so I should rewrite this table to something like this: `ID` -> `PID` -> `CODE` (one column with multiple values assigned to one `ID`), is that right?